# how to Install bash script in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: bash, ubuntu, dcm4che

Hello i am new in Ubuntu environment  i am try to run DCM4CHEE-ARC-LIGHT but this Auto install script unable to run please help me to execute this bash script

```
----Instructions---
It must be installed by root, download and decompress the attached shar file to your /root folder
You must have an internet connection, because it downloads a lot from the net.


Install shar utils
apt-get install sharutils

bash run_me.sh
x - created directory Downloads.
x - extracting Downloads/pacs_start.sh (text)
x - extracting Downloads/pacs_stop.sh (text)
x - extracting install_dcm4chee5_cli_5.10.3.sh (text)
uudecoding file install_dcm4chee5_cli_5.10.3.sh
x - removed lock directory _sh25000.

chmod +x install_dcm4chee5_cli_5.10.3.sh

./install_dcm4chee5_cli_5.10.3.sh

Press enter when asked.


At the end there are some instruction, and hopefully ,  you will have the server (dcm4chee 5.10.3 Mysql secure ui) installed and running.
```

after execute `bash run_me.sh.xz`   this command following error show

```
run_me.sh.xz: run_me.sh.xz: cannot execute binary file
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["cannot execute binary file" when trying to run a shell script on linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37378375/cannot-execute-binary-file-when-trying-to-run-a-shell-script-on-linux)

Comment: The file is compressed with `xz`, you need to remove the compression before it can be used for anything.

Comment: Decompress it with: `xz -d run_me.sh.xz` first.

Answer (score 0):

Please install extra utility packages.

Here's the command sequence:

```
$ sudo apt-get install xz-utils 
$ unxz run_me.sh.xz
```